# Generalized Pépin-Test (Problem understanding a paper)

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, primality-test, quadratic-reciprocity

I am reading [this paper](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebosma/pubs/MathComp1993.pdf) (but you don't need to, I will write down what is needed for the question), and I have difficulty  understanding a certain conclusion.

> $(1.1)\ \ $ $n = 2^k+1$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $3^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod n.$

I totally understand this, the Pépin-Test.

The paper raises the problem

> **Problem $(2.3)$**. Given an odd integer $h > 1$. Determine a finite set $\mathfrak{D}$ and for every positive integer $k \geq 2$ an integer $D\in \mathfrak{D}$ such that $\left(\frac{D}{h\cdot 2^k+1}\right) \neq 1$ and $D\not\equiv 0 \pmod{h\cdot 2^k+1}$.

where$\left(\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}\right)$ is the Jacobi-Symbol. I do understand this problem.

Later, the author claims

> $(3.1)\quad$ Let $n=h\cdot 2^k+1$ with $h\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$, $k\geq 2$.
> Then $\mathfrak{D}=\{3\}$ and $D_k = 3$ for $k\geq 2$ solves $(2.3)$. In particular, If $2^k>h$, then $n$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow 3^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod n$.

I could prove this, also.

Now comes my question. The author says

> The first observation we make is that a solution to Problem $(2.3)$ for one
> particular $h$ will in general lead to a solution for every $h'$ in the same residue
> class modulo $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak{D}}D$. In that light, $(3.1)$ is in fact a consequence of $(1.1)$ and the special case $h = 5$ and $\mathfrak{D} = \{3\}$.

I don't know how to handle this sentence. Unfortunately, I don't understand the special case.
So, $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak{D}}D = 3$, still. But the residue classes $5\pmod 3$ are $-4,-1,2,5,8...$ and so on. But $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak{D}}D = 3$ also solves $h \equiv 1,4,7...$.

I know that in my case $\left(\frac{D}{h\cdot 2^k + 1}\right)$ is the same as $\left(\frac{-D}{h\cdot 2^k + 1}\right)$, so I could come up with that. But I think this is not what the sentence wants to express.
I do not understand this claim.

Answer (score 2):

Let us introduce Problem $(2.3')$.

**Problem $(2.3')$**. Given an odd integer $h > 1$. Determine a finite set $\mathfrak{D}$, an integer $\ell\ge2$ and for every positive integer $k \geq l$ an integer $D\in \mathfrak{D}$ such that $\left(\frac{D}{h\cdot 2^k+1}\right) \neq 1$ and $D\not\equiv 0 \pmod{h\cdot 2^k+1}$.

**Claim**: If we have solved problem $(2.3')$ for $h$, then we can solve problem $(2.3)$ for $h$ as well.
**Proof**: Suppose we have $h, \mathfrak D, \ell$ and $k\to D$ as prescribed in $(2.3')$. There are only finitely many integers $k$ such that $2\le k<\ell$. For each such $k$, choose $$a_{h,k}=\begin{cases}
\text{a positive non-quadratic residue of }h\cdot2^k+1&\text{ if }h\cdot 2^k+1\text{ is prime}\\
\text{a prime factor of } h\cdot 2^k+1 &\text{ if }h\cdot 2^k+1\text{ is not prime}\\
\end{cases}$$
Then $h, \mathfrak D\cup\{a_{h,k}\mid 2\le k<\ell\}$, $k\to\begin{cases}a_{h,k}&\text{ if } 2\le k< l\\D&\text{ if } k\ge\ell\end{cases}$ can be used for problem $(2.3)$.

---

> The first observation we make is that a solution to Problem $(2.3)$ for one particular $h$ will in general lead to a solution for every $h'$ in the same residue class modulo $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak{D}}D$.

Suppose for a particular odd integer $h > 1$, we have found a solution to Problem $(2.3)$, i.e., a finite set $\mathfrak{D}_h$ and for every positive integer $k \geq 2$ an integer $D_{h,k}\in \mathfrak{D}_h$ such that $\left(\frac{D_{h,k}}{h\cdot 2^k+1}\right) \neq 1$ and $D_{h,k}\not\equiv 0 \mod{h\cdot 2^k+1}$.

Suppose we have another odd integer $h'>1$ such that $h'\equiv h \bmod(\prod\limits_{d\in\mathfrak D_h}d)$. I use letter $d$ instead of $D$ as the dummy index variable in the product so as to avoid the abuse of letter $D$. Of course, $\prod\limits_{d\in\mathfrak D_h}d$ and $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak D_h}D$ mean the same number.

In order to show that we can find a solution of $(2.3)$ for $h'$ as well, it is enough to show that we can find a solution of $(2.3')$ for $h'$, thanks to the claim above.

Let $\mathfrak{D}_{h'}=\mathfrak D_h$, $\ell=\lceil\displaystyle{\log_2\left(\frac{\max_{d\in\mathfrak D_{h}}d}{h'}\right)}\rceil$
and for every positive integer $k\ge\ell$, $D_{h',k}=D_{h,k}$.

- $D_{h',k}\in \mathfrak{D}_{h'}$
- We have $$\begin{align}\left(\frac{D_{h',k}}{h'\cdot 2^k+1}\right) &= \left(\frac{h'\cdot 2^k+1}{D_{h',k}}\right)\tag{1a}\\
  &= \left(\frac{h'\cdot 2^k+1}{D_{h,k}}\right)\tag{1b}\\
  &= \left(\frac{h\cdot 2^k+1}{D_{h,k}}\right)\tag{1c}\\
  &= \left(\frac{D_{h,k}}{h\cdot 2^k+1}\right)\tag{1d}\\
  &\neq 1\tag{1e}\end{align}$$
  Explanations:
  $(1a)$: Since $k\ge2$, $h'\cdot2^k+1\equiv1\mod4$. Apply the law of quadratic reciprocity for Jacobi symbol.
  $(1b)$:  $D_{h',k}=D_{h,k}$.
  $(1c)$:  Since $h'\equiv h \bmod\prod\limits_{d\in\mathfrak D_h}d$, we have $h'\cdot 2^k+1\equiv h\cdot 2^k+1\bmod\prod\limits_{d\in\mathfrak D_h}d$.  Since $D_{h,k}\in \mathfrak D_h$, $h'\cdot 2^k+1\equiv h\cdot 2^k+1\bmod D_{h,k}$
  $(1d)$: Similar to $(1a)$.
  $(1e)$: Assumption.
- $0<D_{h',k}\le\displaystyle{\max_{d\in\mathfrak D_{h}}d} \le h'\cdot 2^\ell< h'\cdot 2^k+1.$

  Hence $D_{h',k}\not\equiv 0 \mod{h'\cdot 2^k+1}$.

---

> ... $(3.1)$ is in fact a consequence of $(1.1)$ and the special case $h = 5$ and $\mathfrak{D} = \{3\}$

$(1.1)$ is the special case of $(3.1)$ with $h=1$.

"the special case $h = 5$ and $\mathfrak{D} = \{3\}$" refers to the special case of $(3.1)$ with $h=5$.

In other words, $(3.1)$ is the consequence of two special cases of itself. A clearer statement could have been

> ... $(3.1)$ is in fact a consequence of two special cases of itself, the case $h=1$, which is $(1.1)$ and the case $h = 5$.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying. So I was confused by the sentence itself, but I get this.  What I still do not get is the meaning of "h' in the same residue class mod $\prod\limits_{D\in\mathfrak{D}}D$. So, let's say, for a fixed $h$ I have $\mathfrak{D} = \{3,5,7\}$. And $D$ works. Then $D$ works for $h' = h \pmod{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}$, too?

Comment: @mathquester Please check my updated answer. For a fixed $h$, $\mathfrak D_{h'}$ that we will construct may vary for different $h'\equiv h\bmod {\prod_{d\in\mathfrak D_h}d}$.

Comment: thank you for your time. I am working through your answer, yet I have some questions. So first of all, I showed that $\left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow gcd(D,n) > 1.$ So, for the test it would even be ok to get the result 0, because then I can conclude that $n$ is composite. I think you mean that with the case $h\cdot 2^k+1$ is not prime.
But how do I choose an element $D$ wisely? I do not know whether $n$ is composite or prime. Let's say, I knew the prime decomposition of $h$. Then I only knew which $D$ is NOT to choose. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @mathquester Your comment is clear and correct to me until I read "How do I choose an element $D$ wisely...". Please tell me the first place in my answer that you do not understand yet.

Comment: My Problem is more general I think. I want an element $D$, such that $\left( \frac{h\cdot 2^k+1}{D}\right) = -1.$ Up to now I only know that I can't choose a divisor of $h$. So the question is. how do I find such an element less than "brute-force", i.e. trying the elements except the divisors of $h$.

Comment: @mathquester It looks you are talking about a different problem other than *the question*. I am afraid I have no idea beyond how we may/should understand the quoted parts of that paper.

Comment: Sorry @Apass.Jack you're right. I confused this with another question I had. My bad, sorry for that. I will work through your answer again. Would be glad if you would still help me out if I have another question. Sorry for being confused.

Comment: I got the idea of your answer now, @Apass.Jack (why can't I highlight your name here?). So thank you for that. The question that is still open for me in general is: How do I find a quadratic nonresidue? I think, for fixed $h$, the set $\mathfrak{D}$ will not be finite, but still, I could not prove it.

Comment: It is great that you got the idea in my answer. It looks you are asking a different question in your last comment. I am afraid I might not know how to make progress further. I will keep an eye on your last question, [is there a finite set $\mathfrak{D}$ such that $\left(\frac{h\cdot 2^k+1}{p}\right) \neq 1$ for all $p\in\mathfrak{D}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644486/is-there-a-finite-set-mathfrakd-such-that-left-frach-cdot-2k1p-rig).

Comment: @mathquester If my answer have not solved this question, 4638400, please tell me. Otherwise, could you accept my answer?

Comment: So sorry, I was very sick the last days so I could not do the math. I will work thorugh this again and ask or accept, sorry man, thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. No problem. Take your time.